# Restrict Download Video in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming

I have so many video files ,
that i am putting to my webpage in asp.net.That is working fine.But what i want is users only watch the video only on my site,I have to restrict user to download my video .How do i do that can u please provide me the solution in dotnet.

Is there any other techniques to restrict user download my videos

Comment: I'm sure Warner Brothers would love an answer to this question too...

Answer (score 2):

In my thought , it is impossible....

If you can see it, you already got it.....